# PL SQL : custom data type declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have create a package with a function like this :

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE TRANSAC_ERRONNEES AS

TYPE dateArrayVar IS TABLE OF DATE;

FUNCTION calc_date_moyenne(dateArrayIn dateArrayVar                    
                       ) RETURN DATE; 
END TRANSAC_ERRONNEES;
```

Body :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TRANSAC_ERRONNEES AS
  FUNCTION calc_date_moyenne(dateArrayIn datearrayvar) RETURN DATE IS 
    dateFinal DATE;
    tempsEnSeconde NUMBER;
    tempsMoyenEnSeconde NUMBER;  
  BEGIN
      tempsEnSeconde := 0;
      tempsMoyenEnSeconde := 0;

      FOR i IN 1..dateArrayIn.count loop
        tempsEnSeconde := to_number(to_char(dateArrayIn(i), 'HH24')) * 60 * 60 + to_number(to_char(dateArrayIn(i), 'MI')) * 60 + to_number(to_char(dateArrayIn(i), 'SS'));
        tempsMoyenEnSeconde := tempsMoyenEnSeconde+tempsEnSeconde;
      end loop;

      tempsMoyenEnSeconde := tempsMoyenEnSeconde/dateArrayIn.count;
      dateFinal := to_date(TO_CHAR(dateArrayIn(1),'DD-MM-YYYY') || ' ' || TO_CHAR(to_date(tempsMoyenEnSeconde,'sssss'), 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
      dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(dateFinal,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
      RETURN dateFinal;
  END calc_date_moyenne;
END TRANSAC_ERRONNEES;
/
```

I try to test this function like this :

```
DECLARE
  dates dateArrayVar;
  resultat DATE;

BEGIN
 dates := dateArrayVar(SYSDATE, SYSDATE);
 resultat := transac_erronnees.calc_date_moyenne(dates);
END;
```

I'm getting this following error :

> PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is
>   incomplete or malformed

Please let me know the error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using it in incorrect way. You need to use array with `extend` to assign memory and then assign value in it.

```
DECLARE
  dates dateArrayVar;
  resultat DATE;

BEGIN
 dates.extend(2); -- Since you want to assign two values, extend by 2
 dates(1) := SYSDATE;
 dates(2) := SYSDATE;
 resultat := transac_erronnees.calc_date_moyenne(dates);
END;
```

Update: Second thing is that DateArrayVar has scope only within the package that you have created, in the anonymous block, Oracle cannot see that declaration. One solution is to create external type that is visible to all other procedures and anonymous block or to test, create a procedure within the package and call it from out side.

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE TRANSAC_ERRONNEES AS

TYPE dateArrayVar IS TABLE OF DATE;

FUNCTION calc_date_moyenne(dateArrayIn dateArrayVar                    
                       ) RETURN DATE; 
PROCEDURE test;
END TRANSAC_ERRONNEES;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TRANSAC_ERRONNEES AS
  FUNCTION calc_date_moyenne(dateArrayIn datearrayvar) RETURN DATE IS 
    dateFinal DATE;
    tempsEnSeconde NUMBER;
    tempsMoyenEnSeconde NUMBER;  
  BEGIN
      tempsEnSeconde := 0;
      tempsMoyenEnSeconde := 0;

      FOR i IN 1..dateArrayIn.count loop
        tempsEnSeconde := to_number(to_char(dateArrayIn(i), 'HH24')) * 60 * 60 + to_number(to_char(dateArrayIn(i), 'MI')) * 60 + to_number(to_char(dateArrayIn(i), 'SS'));
        tempsMoyenEnSeconde := tempsMoyenEnSeconde+tempsEnSeconde;
      end loop;

      tempsMoyenEnSeconde := tempsMoyenEnSeconde/dateArrayIn.count;
      dateFinal := to_date(TO_CHAR(dateArrayIn(1),'DD-MM-YYYY') || ' ' || TO_CHAR(to_date(tempsMoyenEnSeconde,'sssss'), 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
      dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(dateFinal,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
      RETURN dateFinal;
  END calc_date_moyenne;

PROCEDURE test
  dates dateArrayVar;
  resultat DATE;

BEGIN
     dates.extend(2); -- Since you want to assign two values, extend by 2
     dates(1) := SYSDATE;
     dates(2) := SYSDATE;
     resultat := transac_erronnees.calc_date_moyenne(dates);
END;
END TRANSAC_ERRONNEES;
/
```

And to test, call it as

```
BEGIN
  TRANSAC_ERRONNEES.TEST;
END;
/
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for helping, I already tried that, but I get the same error :/

Comment: I have this error during the exectuin of the package creation : 

Error(22,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DATES" when expecting one of the following:     ( ; is with authid as cluster order using external    deterministic parallel_enable pipelined The symbol "is" was substituted for "DATES" to continue.

I will explore this way : "DateArrayVar has scope only within the package that you have created"

Answer (score 0):

> DateArrayVar has scope only within the package

I found the solution : I had to specifiate the package : TRANSAC_ERRONNEES.dateArrayVar;

So :

```
DECLARE
  dates TRANSAC_ERRONNEES.dateArrayVar;
  resultat DATE;

BEGIN
 dates := TRANSAC_ERRONNEES.dateArrayVar(SYSDATE, SYSDATE);
 resultat := transac_erronnees.calc_date_moyenne(dates);
 dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(resultat,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
END;
```

It's works now, Thanks